# Getting ViewController from TabBarController Best Practices

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on a car app. 
I have a tabBar linked to different view controllers (CarInfoViewController is one of them).

I'm passing data to one of the view controller using the following way

```
CarInfoViewController *myCarInfoController =  [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
[myCarInfoController setSearchParam:vin];
```

I want to know what is the difference between getting the view controller directly from the TabBar using objectAtIndex vs. doing the following :

```
CarInfoViewController *myCarInfoController = [[CarInfoViewController alloc] init];
[myCarInfoController setSearchParam:vin];
```

Both ways are working! I'm curious to see what is the best practice in such case.

Comment: Best practices depend on how you actually created the tab bar controller. All three ways (referring to my answer) are perfectly 'legal' and having their advantages and disadvantages each, each of them may be the right choice for you. And gong from there we can discuss best practices of accessing individual view controllers for passing data to them. PLUS you should explain under which circumstances you need to pass data. There may be smarter ways then getting hold of the view controller and setting its properties. But that depends very much on the specific case/situation your are in.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thanks! I'm creating the view controller programmatically, and wasn't sure which way to go. But your answer gave me a good understanding. Appreciate it.

Comment: Good, when you create it programmatically then I suggest to hold a reference (property or regular instance variable within App Delegate or a local variable within the method if it is used in the method only) myCarInfoController is a local variable already. Just keep the reference for later usage. Then you are not depending on the view controller of interest being exactly the third view controller within the tab bar structure.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thats a really good idea! and thats why i thought about the 2nd approach so i don't have to rely on the view controller being at index 2. danke!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that both work fine. 
Unless, of course, when you create the view controllers programmatically anyway and it is the very `myCarInfoController` object that you created and add it to the tab bar controller later.

With your first statement you receive a controller from your tab bar. That may well be a controller which was created in Interface Builder or Storyboard Editor respecteively. Of this view controller you know that it is the one in tab no. 3 (index no. 2)

Your second statement allocated a brand new instance of your `CarInfoViewController`. Assuming that there is one already that was created before (in IB or so) and resides as 3rd controller in your tab bar controller, then you have two intances of the same class which are not related to each other. if you know pass any data to `myCarInfoController` (of variant 2) then nothing at all will happen in/to that very instance that is acutally used by the tab bar controller.